# static files django channels

Tags: javascript, django, websocket, django-channels

I'have problem in my home page of notifications systeme. I'm follow this course 
https://arunrocks.com/understanding-django-channels/ this is my js code

```
    <script src="{% static '/channels/js/websocketbridge.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const webSocketBridge = new channels.WebSocketBridge();
  const nl = document.querySelector("#notifylist");

  webSocketBridge.connect('/notifications/');
  webSocketBridge.listen(function(action, stream) {
    console.log("RESPONSE:", action);
    if(action.event == "New User") {
      var el = document.createElement("li");
      el.innerHTML = `New user <b>${action.username}</b> has joined!`;
      nl.appendChild(el);
    }
  })
  document.ws = webSocketBridge; /* for debugging */
})
</script>
```

in console this error is appears
[image]

Comment: Did you add websocketbridge.js from the repository? It is under `/js` . At the time the tutorial was written it was bundled with Django Channels.

Comment: assuming you are using channels v2 then the js is no longer included as part of this.